# mysql(i): Selecting data from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Say if I have 2 tables. The first one holds users ids and their first names. The second one holds user ids and their last names, but the rows in this table may or may not exist depending on whether the user has given their last name or not.

I want to select both the first name and the last name, but if only the first name exists then to just select that on its own.

I cant use something like this because if the second table row doesn't exist then it returns nothing:

```
$db->query("select firstname.fname, lastname.lname from firstname, lastname where firstname.userid = lastname.userid");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Now is the time to start learning about the different JOINS.... have a read of http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html ... it's a very good explanation, that should put you on the right track

Comment: theres no way to do it without joins? ;p

Comment: by its very nature, executing a query that retrieves data from two tables requires a join... and it really is worthwhile learning about the different SQL joins, and when and how to use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT f.fname, l.lname
FROM firstname f
   LEFT JOIN lastname l
      ON f.userid = l.userid
```

this will return something like:

```
fname | lname
John  | Doe
Bob   | NULL
```

where `NULL` means that Bob hasn't got a last name

`JOIN` is more performant than cartesian product you are using in your example because it won't produce all the possible combinations of `{firstame,lastname}` but just the ones which make sense (the ones with the same userid)

Comment: f is an ALIAS for firstname so when you refer to firstname on your query you can use just f, this is just for sake of brevity